# Convert sent params to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have controller method which perform some actions for POST sent json params, but the problem is when I try to send json params without json header. 
I would like to handle this exception by converting string to json and here the problems begins. 
Let's say that I have simple JSON like this:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

I have placed `binding.pry` at the begining of method and I try to get params from there. I figured out that `request.body` will return me object `#<StringIO:0x007fbdb5cf9fe8>` which I have to convert to JSON. 
First thing I have tried was:

```
[1] pry(#<TestController>)> request.body.to_json
=> "[\"{\\\"menu\\\": {\\n\",\"  \\\"id\\\": \\\"file\\\",\\n\",\"  \\\"value\\\": \\\"File\\\",\\n\",\"  \\\"popup\\\": {\\n\",\"    \\\"menuitem\\\": [\\n\",\"      {\\\"value\\\": \\\"New\\\", \\\"onclick\\\": \\\"CreateNewDoc()\\\"},\\n\",\"      {\\\"value\\\": \\\"Open\\\", \\\"onclick\\\": \\\"OpenDoc()\\\"},\\n\",\"      {\\\"value\\\": \\\"Close\\\", \\\"onclick\\\": \\\"CloseDoc()\\\"}\\n\",\"    ]\\n\",\"  }\\n\",\"}}\"]"
```

but it is not result I was looking for. 
I have tried several more converts, like:

```
[2] pry(#<TestsController>)> ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.to_json)                                                                                                                                                                                                
=> []
```

Which also gives me nothing. I'm out of ideas.
I would like to achive something like this:

```
[1] pry(#<TestsController>)> params
=> {"menu"=>{"id"=>"file", "value"=>"File", "popup"=>{"menuitem"=>[{"value"=>"New", "onclick"=>"CreateNewDoc()"}, {"value"=>"Open", "onclick"=>"OpenDoc()"}, {"value"=>"Close", "onclick"=>"CloseDoc()"}]}},
 "controller"=>"payments",
 "action"=>"notification",
 "payment"=>{"menu"=>{"id"=>"file", "value"=>"File", "popup"=>{"menuitem"=>[{"value"=>"New", "onclick"=>"CreateNewDoc()"}, {"value"=>"Open", "onclick"=>"OpenDoc()"}, {"value"=>"Close", "onclick"=>"CloseDoc()"}]}}}}
```

This is scenario for sending params with json header. In that can I can easily iterate through them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `JSON.parse` on `request.body.read`

```
request.body.rewind
JSON.parse(request.body.read)
```

Comment: Why are you using rewind?

Comment: @Gregy I'm resetting stream to the beginning, in case it is already read by someone

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried 
request.body replaced with env['rack.input'].read

```
json = JSON.parse env['rack.input'].read
```

OR

```
json = JSON.parse request.body.read
```

as stated [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/08/17/ruby-receive-json-in-request-body/)

Comment: It returns TypeError: can't convert StringIO into String

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using RoR, if you are using [Action Controller Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) you can use the `to_hash` method and then use `to_json` (which is only on RoR, not part of Ruby) to convert your permitted params, like this:

```
params.permit(:attributes).to_hash.to_json
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this worked:

```
JSON.parse(params[:attributes].to_json)
```